# Missing element of the sequence

Tags: sequence

Could you find the missing symbol in the sequence shown below?

[image: the puzzle image]

Hope you like :-)

Comment: (Why not just copy this image here so it's hosted "in network", rather than trying to keep up with changes to the original URL?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These look to me like

> Chinese numerals, somewhat stylized, mirrored on two axes.

In that case, the next one would be something like this:

> [image]